# How to run a subgit import for trunk and one specific branch

Tags: subgit

Hi I have a question about SubGit version 3.2.1 ('Bobique') build #3593.

The svn repo to import doesn't have a standard layout.

I can't find the documentation to configure a 'subgit import' for just a trunk and one specific branch on the same level as trunk. The branches are not in a branches folder.

In other words..

In svn we got a trunk which should be mapped to master.
In svn we have branch x, which should be mapped to develop.

I hope I have been clear. Can anybody help me?

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can run

```
$ subgit configure --svn-url PROJECT_ROOT repo.git
```

Then edit repo.git/subgit/config depending on the following condition. If you want continuous synchronization, do you want other branches be ever translated (e.g. when someone pushes refs/heads/new branch, should it be translated to SVN)? If yes, you should have the following configuration:

```
trunk = trunk:refs/heads/master
branches = x:refs/heads/develop
branches = *:refs/heads/*
#it's up to you whether you want to have tags/shelves or not
#shelves = shelves/*:refs/shelves/*
#tags = tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

If no, you can specify that certain branch only:

```
trunk = trunk:refs/heads/master
branches = x:refs/heads/develop
#it's up to you whether you want to have tags/shelves or not
#shelves = shelves/*:refs/shelves/*
#tags = tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

In the second case when you push refs/heads/branch, SubGit will ignore it.
If you need just one time translation, both configuration are the same.

Finally, run

```
$ subgit install repo.git
```

If you don't need continuous synchronization, you can then run

```
$ subgit uninstall repo.git
```